# use of string format in python, to generate repeated text messages

Tags: python

I have:

```
inventory = ["shoes, 12, 29.99", "shirts, 20, 9.99", "sweatpants, 25, 15.00", "scarves, 13, 7.75"]
for item in inventory:
    print('The store has {1} {0}, each for {2} USD'.format(item))
```

and I am trying to get:
The store has 12 shoes, each for 29.99 USD
.
.
.

Comment: the value of item in each iteration of the loop is just a string, you need it to be a list or tuple that can be used to replace your placeholders

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Print items in a List of Strings using the format method in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753148/how-to-print-items-in-a-list-of-strings-using-the-format-method-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `split`:

```
inventory = ["shoes, 12, 29.99", "shirts, 20, 9.99", "sweatpants, 25, 15.00", "scarves, 13, 7.75"]
for item in inventory:
    print('The store has {1} {0}, each for {2} USD'.format(*item.split(', ')))
```

Output:

```
The store has 12 shoes, each for 29.99 USD
The store has 20 shirts, each for 9.99 USD
The store has 25 sweatpants, each for 15.00 USD
The store has 13 scarves, each for 7.75 USD
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to split the `item` in for loop, so that you can use those value in `.format` method.

```
inventory = ["shoes, 12, 29.99", "shirts, 20, 9.99", "sweatpants, 25, 15.00", "scarves, 13, 7.75"]
for item in inventory:
    print('The store has {1} {0}, each for {2} USD'.format(*item.split(',')))
```